# How to build an exe file from a specific form. C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Visual Studio C# project with about 5 different forms. Is it possible to build an .exe file from a specific form? To be more precise I have a Form1 with a button and when I click it I want it to compile the Form2 code into a separate .exe file. Is this possible?

Comment: You should split forms between different projects

Comment: I'm curious – why do you want this?

Comment: Splitting forms between different projects isn't an option since I want the user to enter information like Username and Password and then for the program to compile the Form2 into an .exe with that information.

Comment: Seconding "why do you want this"?.  Whatever the actual problem trying to be solved is, I suspect there is an easier way.

Comment: I want a user to enter information like Username, Password and things like that which would be given to the Form2 and build in to a .exe file. Which when the user opens would execute the code with the preferences he selected in Form1 before.

Comment: I caution you against compiling a username and password into an exe.  Decompilers and other analyzers can easily retrieve that information just as if you put it into a plain text file

Comment: You should split forms into projects and make Form2 and Form3 accept parameters. You don't need to compile a project each time you have different variables to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not unless you separate the forms into different projects, as mentioned above.

However I'm not sure that's what you really want to do – a probably nicer way is to parse the command line parameters in your app's `Program.cs` where `Form1` is probably currently being instantiated as the main form for your app, and instead choose another form – something like

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YourApp
{
    internal sealed class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Form form = null;
            if(Array.IndexOf(args, "--form2") > -1) form = new Form2();
            else if(Array.IndexOf(args, "--form3") > -1) form = new Form3();
            else if(Array.IndexOf(args, "--form4") > -1) form = new Form4();
            else form = new Form1();
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

should work, and then just launch your executable with one of those parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build 5 different exe file, create 5 different projects... Add reference of a project into another project to access values in project (see also circular dependency).